# What is a good approach to modeling objects with too many details?

Tags: modeling

I need help on what approach I should use to make these two models:

[image]

[image]

With so many details like that, It seems using SubD Modeling will require a tons of edge loops and the topology would be extremely complex. But using Boolean techniques will result in a great deal of shading issues and a lack of smoothness.

So how can these two models be made in Blender?

Comment: Maybe the addon DECALmachine can help you with faking a lot of small details. It is not free though (40$ as of today).

Comment: Thank you. I would like to model those details with real geometry though.

Comment: Maybe you should try HardOps for Blender...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOr0RBraRaI

and BoxCutter…
https://blendermarket.com/products/hard-ops--boxcutter-ultimate-bundle

Answer (score 1):

These objects are pretty detailed and might require some time to create, but you definitely don't need any paid add-ons.

So here's how I would recreate the lower model:

1. Start with a cylinder.
2. Taper the rear end.
3. Extensively use boolean to cut out undesired portions. The basic shape of this model should be almost completely re-creatable with `Boolean` modifiers. Don't worry about things like smoothness just yet, you're still roughing out the piece.
4. Make a safety-copy of your mesh and `Apply` all the previously created boolean modifiers. In edit-mode select the sharp edges that should be smoother and hit `Bevel Edges` (with the mouse wheel the "roundness" of these new bevel can be increased).
5. Add and apply a `Multiresolution` modifier (set to simple **not** Catmull-Clarck) and add final details to the mesh.
6. (If the polygon count is too high) Create another copy of the mesh, reduce it's polygon count with the `Remesh` modifier and bake the details of the high-poly mesh to the low-poly mesh using normal-maps.

If this is hard to understand by just reading through, I'd recommend this extensive [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgHJVJF3T3CFUAZ6z11jKg6a).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Orc.